# Jboss war redeployment Zipexception

Tags: linux, ant, jboss

> Server:       jboss-5.1.0
> Java Version: jdk1.6.0_14
> Deployment Method: ant v1.7
> Error: 08:40:04,260 WARN  [ZipEntryContext] IGNORING: Failed to reinitialize context: vfszip:/home/username/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/deployment.war
> java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Error occurs if the server is running and I run an ant deploy on my src code. This is all being done via VI on our server.

I have searched our JBOSS settings but I can't seem to find the correct one to get rid of this error. Ideas?

### Update

Here is our deployment method:

```
 <target name="deploy" depends="war" description="--> The deploy target (initially empty)">
    <copy file="scripts/xmlscript.groovy" todir="${jboss.bin.dir}" overwrite="true"/>
    <copy file="grails-app/views/xmlService/current.xml" todir="${jboss.bin.dir}" overwrite="true"/>
    <copy file="${war.file}" todir="${jboss.deploy.dir}" overwrite="true"/>
</target>
```

Comment: What does "ant deploy" perform exactly? Does it build the war under JBoss `deploy` directory or does it copy a WAR?

Comment: Edited post to add in our deployment method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but, according to [JBAS-6612](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS-6612):

> This is an issue due to the fact that the copy **is not** atomic. To work around this issue temporarily, use the move command instead as it **is** atomic.

Could you try to use the Ant [move](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) task instead of copy?

Comment: Thank you very much. This seemed to fix our problem.

Comment: Link broken for ant move task.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say, but my guess is that JBoss is trying to open and deploy your WAR file before it has been fully copied by Ant. This is always the risk when copying into the `deploy` directory of a running JBoss server.

It's safer to do this only when JBoss is turned off, although obviously that's not an ideal situation. Alternatively, you can either disable the deployment scanner (which automatically detects deployable content under `deploy`) and manually control deployments via JMX (which is a bit fiddly), or you can reduce the frequency that the deployment scanner runs (which default to every 5 seconds, defined in `deploy/hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml`).

Comment: Great advice Skaffman but, it seems as if it did NOT fix our issue.